# How to encrypt a file in java using AES

Tags: java, file, encryption, key, aes

I need to know how to create an AES and using it to encrypt and decrypt a file in java.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915644/java-aes-decrypting-problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption shows you how to encrypt a string using AES. To encrypt a File, just read the contents as String, encrypt it and write it back to file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a `CipherOutputStream` and passing in a `FileOutputStream`. See http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/UsingCipherOutputStream.htm for a quick example, just use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` instead.